# VTDecompressionSessionDecodeFrame fails with code -kVTVideoDecoderBadDataErr

Tags: ios, avfoundation

I have been trying to decode H264 using VTDecompressionSessionDecodeFrame but getting errors. The Parameter sets have been created previously and look fine, nothing errors up to this point so it may have something to do with my understanding of Timing information in the CMSampleBufferRef. Any input would be much appreciated

```
void didDecompress( void *decompressionOutputRefCon, void *sourceFrameRefCon, OSStatus status, VTDecodeInfoFlags infoFlags, CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer, CMTime presentationTimeStamp, CMTime presentationDuration ){

    NSLog(@"In decompression callback routine");
```

}

```
void decodeH264 { 

VTDecodeInfoFlags infoFlags;
[NALPacket appendBytes: NalPacketSize length:4];
                    [NALPacket appendBytes: &NALCODE length:1];
                    [NALPacket appendBytes: startPointer length:buflen];
                    void *samples = (void *)[NALTestPacket bytes];

                    blockBuffer = NULL;

                    // add the nal raw data to the CMBlockBuffer
                    status = CMBlockBufferCreateWithMemoryBlock(
                                                                kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                                samples,
                                                                [NALPacket length],
                                                                kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                                NULL,
                                                                0,
                                                                [NALPacket length],
                                                                0,
                                                                &blockBuffer);

                        const size_t * samplesizeArrayPointer;
                        size_t sampleSizeArray= buflen;
                        samplesizeArrayPointer = &sampleSizeArray;

                        int32_t timeSpan = 1000000;
                        CMTime PTime = CMTimeMake(presentationTime, timeSpan);
                        CMSampleTimingInfo timingInfo;
                        timingInfo.presentationTimeStamp = PTime;
                        timingInfo.duration =  kCMTimeZero;
                        timingInfo.decodeTimeStamp = kCMTimeInvalid;

                        status = CMSampleBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, blockBuffer, YES, NULL, NULL, formatDescription, 1, 1, &timingInfo, 0, samplesizeArrayPointer, &sampleBuffer);

                        CFArrayRef attachmentsArray = CMSampleBufferGetSampleAttachmentsArray(sampleBuffer, true);
                        for (CFIndex i = 0; i < CFArrayGetCount(attachmentsArray); ++i) {
                            CFMutableDictionaryRef attachments = (CFMutableDictionaryRef)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(attachmentsArray, i);
                            CFDictionarySetValue(attachments, kCMSampleAttachmentKey_DoNotDisplay, kCFBooleanFalse);
                            CFDictionarySetValue(attachments, kCMSampleAttachmentKey_DisplayImmediately, kCFBooleanTrue);
                        }

// I Frame
                        status = VTDecompressionSessionDecodeFrame(decoder, sampleBuffer, kVTDecodeFrame_1xRealTimePlayback, (void*)CFBridgingRetain(currentTime), &infoFlags);
                         if (status != noErr) {
                             NSLog(@"Decode error");
                         }
```

Answer (score 0):

Discovered why this wasn't working, I had forgotten to set the CMSampleBufferRef to NULL  each time a new sample was captured.

```
samples = NULL;

status = CMSampleBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, blockBuffer, YES, NULL, NULL, formatDescription, 1, 1, &timingInfo, 0, samplesizeArrayPointer, &sampleBuffer);
```

Comment: Would you kindly elaborate? I am getting the same return from VTDecompressionSessionDecodeFrame(), however I can't tell from your comment here exactly what you needed to do to avoid this error return. Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately I can't, this was a bit of trial and error on my part. I am decoding a stream of bits over the network and every time I get a new nal unit and prepare it in a sample buffer I need to set the previously used sample buffer to NULL. Interestingly I have stopped using VTDecompressionDecodeFrame and use the AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer which does a good job of displaying H264 in a layer in your application

Comment: It sounds like your issue was related to memory management of the frame buffers, which ended up being my issue as well. Thanks for the note!